# Concatenate rows in a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I am building up a query and I need to concatenate the values of a column in one single row

I managed it with STRING_AGG function, but unfortunely the database where I am going to use the stored procedure is not the 2017 version, so I am trying with stuff but I can't get it to work

```
select w1.idQuestionario, w1.nominativo, w1.media, w1.valutazione, count(w1.risposto) as Funzionari, (stuff((select a.peso for xml path('')), 1, 0, ',')) as peso, (stuff((select a.titolo for xml path('')), 1, 0, ',')) from (
    select w.nominativo, w.idQuestionario, w.risposto, sum(w.valore) / convert(float, count(w.Domande)) as media, w.valutazione
    from (
    select u.nominativo, q.idQuestionario, q.nome, d.idDomanda as Domande,  r.peso , ur.matricola as risposto, 1 * r.peso as valore, sum(us.valutazione) / convert(float, count(us.idSezione)) as valutazione
    from Questionario q 
    join Domanda d ON d.idQuestionario = q.idQuestionario
    join Risposta r ON r.idDomanda = d.idDomanda
    join rUtenteRisposta ur ON ur.idRisposta = r.idRisposta
    join Utente u ON u.matricola = ur.matricola
    left join rUtenteSezione us ON us.idQuestionario = q.idQuestionario AND us.matricola = u.matricola
    where q.cancellato = 0
    and q.idQuestionario = '111222'
    and q.anonimo = 0
    group by u.nominativo, q.idQuestionario, q.nome, d.idDomanda, r.peso, ur.matricola
    ) w
    group by w.idQuestionario,w.risposto,w.nominativo,w.valutazione ) w1
    join (select r.peso, d.titolo as titolo, u.nominativo, r.creazione from Domanda d
    join Questionario as q ON q.idQuestionario = d.idQuestionario
    join Risposta as r ON r.idDomanda = d.idDomanda
    join rUtenteRisposta as ur on ur.idRisposta = r.idRisposta
    join utente u ON u.matricola = ur.matricola
    where q.idQuestionario = '111222'
    and q.cancellato = 0
    and q.anonimo = 0) a ON a.nominativo = w1.nominativo
    group by w1.idQuestionario, w1.media, w1.nominativo, w1.valutazione, a.peso, a.titolo, a.creazione
    order by a.creazione
```

I was getting this result before stuff:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
aaaaa   bbbbb   0,2     6       1       how are you?
aaaaa   bbbbb   0,2     6       2       did you eat?
ccccc   dddddd  0,5     7       1       how are you?
ccccc   dddddd  0,5     7       1       did you eat?
```

now with stuff I am getting this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
aaaaa   bbbbb   0,2     6       ,<columns5>1,</columns5>       ,<columns6>how are you?,</columns6>
aaaaa   bbbbb   0,2     6       ,<columns5>1,</columns5>       ,<columns6>did you eat?,</columns6>
ccccc   dddddd  0,5     7       ,<columns5>1,</columns5>       ,<columns6>how are you?,</columns6>
ccccc   dddddd  0,5     7       ,<columns5>1,</columns5>       ,<columns6>did you eat?,</columns6>
```

But I would like to achieve this result:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
aaaaa   bbbbb   0,2     6       1, 2    how are you?, did you eat?
ccccc   dddddd  0,5     7       1, 1    how are you?, did you eat?
```

Databases are is SQL Server 2012 and 2014.

Thank you so much for you help

Comment: Are column1, column2, column3, column4,column5 composite unique key ?If not give different example of these columns .

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below:

```
STUFF((SELECT a.peso FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, ',')
```

with

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + a.peso FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

As your expression was just a column, the the values in your XML would be created wrapped in the tags `<peso>`. Also you need to put the comma in the XML at the start, and remove the first character from the string (not just add a single comma at the start).

Also, on a final note, if your column `a.peso` is likely to contain special characters, then I suggest the following:

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + a.peso FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering I tried it but I keep getting the result with the same in the line "I was getting this result before stuff:"

Comment: Likely you need to change the above to a correlated subquery too; but without any sample data, that is impossible to provide an answer to.